# Extract Salesforce Objects and Load them into SQLLite Database Tables- Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to collect data from salesforce and then load them into sqllite tables.

Here is my code:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SFType, SalesforceLogin
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import json 
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint as pp 


    #Connect to salesforce site
session_id, instance = SalesforceLogin(username=username, password=password, security_token=security_token)
    #Create Instance
sf = Salesforce(instance=instance, session_id=session_id)

desc = sf.Opportunity.describe()  

# Below is what you need

field_names = [field['name'] for field in desc['fields']]

soql = "SELECT {} FROM Opportunity ".format(','.join)

results = sf.query_all(soql)

sf_df = pd.DataFrame(results['records']).drop(columns='attributes')


sf_df.to_csv('/Users/ma/test1.csv')
```

This collects the opportunity table and writes it to a CSV file. Any suggestions on how to improve this step and also the next step which is to create a sqllite table out of the salesforce generated csv files? I am new to salesforce and sqllite and am stuck on these steps.

Comment: I don't see where do you use the ```field_names```?
Also, my advice would be write the data directly to the DB without the intermediate step of converting and then importing the CSV file.

Comment: How do you recommend doing that?

Comment: You can read more on how to operate a DB API for SQLite here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
It is not that different from what you did importing the data from salesforce DB